# Function REQUIRESCRIPT may not be used in this type of formula

Tags: visualforce

i am creating a static vf page which have following code :

```
<apex:page>
    <body>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Accounts/Contacts/Cases/Opportunities</legend>
            <ul>
                <li>Go to Setup</li>
                <li>Go to App Setup >> Customize >> Accounts/Contacts/Cases/Opportunities</li>
                <li>Click on Page Layouts.</li>
                <li>Edit the Page Layouts.</li>
                <li>Click on Buttons sections.</li>
                <li>Drag Schedule Meeting button in custom buttons area.</li>
                <li>Save the page layout.</li>
            </ul>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Leads</legend>
            <ul>
                <li>Go to Setup</li>
                <li>Go to App Setup >> Customize >> Leads</li>
                <li>Click on Page Layouts.</li>
                <li>Edit the Page Layouts.</li>
                <li>Click on Buttons sections.</li>
                <li>Drag Schedule Meeting, Invite to GoToMeeting and Schedule a Rep buttons to the custom buttons area.</li>
                <li>Save the page layout.</li>
                <li><font color="red">
    <i>"Note: The "Schedule a Rep" button should only be used if your organization enables Users to Assign meetings to the GoToMeeting Accounts of other Users. This feature enables the User to select from a list of GoToMeeting users, view their calendars, then assign and invite Leads and Contacts to their meetings </i>
    </font></li>
                <li>Next, go to Leads "Search Layouts".</li>
                <li>Click on "Edit" link next to "Leads List View".</li>
                <li>Go to "Available Buttons" and select "Invite to GoToMeeting".</li>
                <li>Click on "Add".</li>
                <li>Click on "Save".</li>
            </ul>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Custom Objects</legend>
            To add the "Scheduled Meeting" button to the detail page of any custom object, copy the followiong code: 
            {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/connection.js")} 
            {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/apex.js")} 
            var namespace = 'GTM'; 
            var clsNamespace =''; 
            if (namespace != '' && namespace != null) { clsNamespace = namespace +'.'; namespace = namespace + '__'; }location.href='/apex/'+namespace+'GTMWizard1?recordId='+'INSERT MERGE FIELD HERE';
            <ul>
                <li>Go to Setup</li>
                <li>Go to App Setup >> Create >> Objects</li>
                <li>Go to your Custom Object</li>
                <li>On your Custom Object go to "Buttons, Links, and Actions"</li>
                <li>Click on "New Button or Link"</li>
                <li>Name your button "Schedule Meeting"</li>
                <li>For "Display Type" select Detail Page Button</li>
                <li>For "Behavior" select "Execute JavaScript"</li>
                <li>For "Content Source" select "onClick javascript"</li>
                <li>Paste the code you just copied</li>
                Highlight "INSERT MERGE FIELD HERE" , then select Record ID from the "Insert Merge Field" picklist
                <br/> Click "Save"
                <br/>
                <li>Scroll up to the Page Layout section</li>
                <li>Edit the Page Layouts</li>
                <li>Click on Buttons sections</li>
                <li>Drag Schedule Meeting button to the custom buttons area</li>
                <li>Click Save</li>
                <br/> To add the "Invite to GoToMeeting" button to the detail page of any custom object, copy the followiong code:
                <br/> var namespace = 'GTM__';
                <br/> location.href = '/apex/'+namespace+'MeetingInvite?recordId='+'INSERT MERGE FIELD HERE';
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <li>Go to Setup</li>
                <li>Go to App Setup >> Create >> Objects</li>
                <li>Go to your Custom Object</li>
                <li>On your Custom Object Go to "Buttons, Links, and Actions"</li>
                <li>Click on "New Button or Link"</li>
                <li>Name your button "Invite to GoToMeeting"</li>
                <li>For "Display Type" select Detail Page Button</li>
                <li>For "Behavior" select "Execute JavaScript"</li>
                <li>For "Content Source" select "onClick JavaScript"</li>
                <li>Paste the code you just copied into the body of the merge field section</li>
                <li>Highlight "INSERT MERGE FIELD HERE" , then select Record ID from the "Insert Merge Field" picklist</li>
                <br/>
                <li>Click "Save"</li>
                <br/>
                <li>Scroll up to the Page Layout section
                    <li>Edit the Page Layouts</li>
                    Click on Buttons sections</li>
                <li>Drag Schedule Meeting button to the custom buttons area</li>
                <li>Click Save</li>
                <br/>
                <h3>Done!</h3>
            </ul>
        </fieldset>
    </body>
</apex:page>
```

I am getting

> Function `REQUIRESCRIPT` may not be used in this type of formula in
>   above code.

Help me to resolve this..

Comment: Shubham- Let me know my Ans worked for you or not?

Comment: i like to print the js code as it is..i would not care if it is working or not..can you help in this

Comment: Shubham check my updated ans i.e. edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like error says you can't use like expression i.e.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/apex.js")}
```

Instead use script tag to load `connection.js` and `apex.js` files

```
<script src="/soap/ajax/10.0/connection.js"> </script >

<script src="/soap/ajax/10.0/apex.js"> </script >
```

One more thing.. **Wrap all your Javascript code inside script tag** then only your script work else won't

```
<script>
var namespace = 'GTM'; 
            var clsNamespace =''; 
            if (namespace != '' && namespace != null) { 
             clsNamespace = namespace +'.'; 
             namespace = namespace + '__'; 
            }
            location.href='/apex/'+namespace+'GTMWizard1?recordId='+'INSERT MERGE FIELD HERE';
</script>
```

---

### **Edit**

Looks like you just want to display the script then use

you need help of controller here

```
public class A {
    public  String str1{get;set;}
     public  String str2{get;set;}
    public  A() {
    str1= '{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/connection.js")}';
     str2= '{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/apex.js")}';
    }    
}
```

Page

```
<apex:outputText value="{!str1}"/><br/>
<apex:outputText value="{!str2}"/>
```

Comment: Alternatively: `<apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/10.0/connection.js" />`... REQUIRESCRIPT is only for custom buttons and links.

Comment: @sfdcfox Correct.. we can use either `<script>` or `<apex:includeScript>` .